# Laravel, localhost works fine, but with laragon {name}.test I get errors

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

Laravel, localhost works fine, but with laragon {name}.test I get errors.

The problem I have is that when I start the server in the Laragon terminal, localhost works perfectly, but in Laragon when I open the page (right click -> www -> {project}) I get errors that I don't get in localhost, for example:

> Undefined variable $txt

my index code:

```
<body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <div class="container-fluid">
             <form class="d-flex" action="{{route('articles.index')}}" method="get">
                 <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="text" value="{{$txt}}">
                 <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                 <a href="{{route('articles.create')}}" class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</a>
             </form>
         </div>
     </nav>
     {{$articles->links()}}
     <div class="div1">
         @if(Session::get('success'))
             <div class="alert alert-success mt-2">
                 <strong>{{Session::get('success')}}</strong><br>
             </div>
         @endif
     </div>

     <div class="site-container">
         <div class="article-container">
             @foreach ($articles as $arti)
             <article class="article-card card">
                 <figure class="article-image">
                     <img src="{{$arti->AImage}}" class="card-img-top img-product" alt="Not found">
                 </figure>
                 <div class="article-content">
                     <a class="card-category">{{$arti->AName}}</a>
                     @if ($arti->APrice==0.0)
                         <h3 class="card-title" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);">Free</h3>
                     @endif
                     @if($arti->APrice>0.0)
                         <h3 class="card-title" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);">{{$arti->APrice}}</h3>
                     @endif
                     <p class="card-excerpt">{{$arti->Adescription}}</p>
                     <p class="card-excerpt">Stock: {{$arti->AStock}}</p>
                     <div class="box">
                         <form action="{{route('articles.stocks',$arti->idArticulos)}}"" class="d-inline f-buy"><a><button type="button" class="btnBuy ">Buy</button></a></form>
                         <button type="button" class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
                         <a href="{{route('articles.edit', $arti->idArticulos)}}"><button class="btnModify">Modify</button></a>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </article>
             @endforeach
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
@endsection
```

localhost:
[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmVtf.png)
with laragon (Pretty URLs):
[Pretty URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqOqp.png)

NOTE: I am new to programming in Laravel

I read that the variables are described in the web.php file, in this case $text and $articulos, I tried it but I got an error regarding {{$articulos->links()}}

mistake:

> Call to a member function links() on string

my web.php code with the changes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    
     return view('index',['txt'=>'','articles'=>'']);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... your view is expecting `$articles` to be a paginated collection of Articles it would seem not a string